# React Native center image horizontally in header

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

[image]

My header.js looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Image, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons"
import { View } from "react-native"

export class Logo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image
          source={require('../../assets/logo.png')}
          resizeMode="contain"
          style={{ width: 98, alignSelf: 'center' }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I try to get logo.png centered in header bar, but alignSelf property does not affect it in any way. Using Android emulator. How can I center the logo horizontally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'` in image parent view :

```js
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', width: '100%'}}>
  <Image
    source={require('../../assets/logo.png')}
    resizeMode="contain"
    style={{ width: 98 }}
  />
</View>
```

And add `headerLayoutPreset: 'center'` in your stackNavigator.

```js
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";

const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  ComponentKey: {
    screen: Component
  },
  ...,
  ..., 
}, {
  headerLayoutPreset: 'center'
});
```

Comment: Nothing changed by adding that. Only noticed if I set width 200% in your suggestion, the img moves to the right.

Comment: Can you please add screenshot ?

Comment: added a screenshot.

Comment: Are you using StackNavigator ? If yes, can you please add some of code ?

Comment: I'm using react-navigation-stack 2.0.16. What code would you like to see? That is my complete header.js.

Comment: I think @ViktorJovanovic answer will help you. Add `headerLayoutPreset: 'center'` to your stackNavigator navigation options.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using react-navigation, I assume you've put a component you want to center instead of the header title! To do this on Android, you have to add this parameter to your navigation!

```js
headerLayoutPreset: 'center',
```

Otherwise, try to apply it on the view that wrap your logo

```js
<View style={{
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
}} >
...
```